# Is this Dynamic Programming Solution to Text Justification just Brute Force?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm having trouble understanding the dynamic programming solution to the text justification problem as specified in the MIT open courseware lecture [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-20-dynamic-programming-ii-text-justification-blackjack/#vid_playlist). Some notes from that lecture are [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec20_orig.pdf), and page 3 of the notes is what I am referring to.

I thought that Dynamic Programming meant you memoize some of the computations so that you don't need to recompute, thus saving you time, but in the algorithm given in the lecture, I don't see any use of memoization, just a whole bunch of deep recursive calls, i.e. the main function is this:

```
DP[i] = min(badness (i, j) + DP[j] for j in range (i + 1, n + 1))
DP[n] = 0
```

where `badness` is a function that determines the the amount of unused space after subtracting the length of the words from the line length. To me it looks like this algorithm calculates all possible "badness" calculations and chooses the smallest one, which seems like brute force to me. Where is the advantage Dynamic Programming usually gives us by memoizing past calculations so we don't have to recompute?

Answer (score 2):

If you memoize the results, you don't have to compute each `DP[i]` several times.

That is, `DP[0]` "calls" `DP[2]` for example, but so does `DP[1]`. In the second time `DP[2]` is called, it won't be necessary to compute it again, you can just return the memoized value.

This also makes it easy to verify a polynomial upper bound for this algorithm. Since each `DP[i]` will perform O(n) operations, and there are `n` of them, the overall algorithm is O(n^2), assuming, of course, that `badness(i, j)` is O(1).

Comment: Yeah, so I guess I'm wondering why there was no mention of this memoizing optimization in the lecture or in the notes..

Comment: @jcm It's because the notes assume all DPs will be implemented as a table in a bottom-up fashion, which doesn't require memoization. For this problem, in special, the table can be constructed in reverse (from n to 0).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by doesn't require memoization. Are you saying that all the results are computed on the fly and therefore we don't have to store anything because there's no duplicated work?

Comment: This answer doesn't address the original question as to why memoization was not used in the recursive solution.